# adding image between line in haml

Tags: html, image, haml

I have the following text that i want to display in haml.

```
<div class="myclass">
My long text here. My word's ...
<img src="link" class="mylinkclass">
</div>
```

Notice the `'` in words. I tried many this possible and have spend hours.

```
%li.event.right
   .header= l("'EGR Operator Award for Financial Betting Operator'")
     .event-body!= l(" My long text's . %img{:class => "responsive" :src => url_for("images/pages/img.jpg")} ")
```

The above code fails. i tried

```
 %li.event.right
    .header= l("'EGR Operator Award for Financial Betting Operator'")
         .event-body!= l(" My long text's . <img class ="responsive" src => url_for("images/pages/img.jpg") ")
```

url_for is not recognized in this case. Please how do i achieved that? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
%li.event.right
  .header= l("'EGR Operator Award for Financial Betting Operator'")
    .event-body
      = l(" My long text's")
      %img{:class => "responsive" :src => url_for("images/pages/img.jpg")}
```

Btw, do you know this page? http://html2haml.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @lch the link is of great help. However, your example above displays the image outside the event-body div. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: It depends on the styling and size of `.event-body`. The HTML should have it inside the `<div class='.event-body'>`